# sql where class in android

Tags: android

hi all
i want to use where clause in the query in android my table structure is 
`id - number
 name - text`
so i wrote query in the following manner:

```
      db = openOrCreateDatabase("TestData.db", SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
       db.setVersion(1);
       db.setLocale(Locale.getDefault());
       db.setLockingEnabled(true);
       final String CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES ="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_countries (id INTEGER);";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COUNTRIES);                 

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("id", rnd.nextInt(50));
    db.insert("tbl_countries", null, values);

             String p=et.getText().toString();
             Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select id from tbl_countries where id="+p  , null); // line no 62.
             if (c != null ) {
                if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                  do {
                     tv1.setText(String.valueOf((c.getInt(0))));
                  }while (c.moveToNext());
                }
             }

             db.close();
```

but i get errors my log cat:

```
   05-23 16:53:16.708: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544): java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to acquire a reference on a close SQLiteClosable
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteClosable.acquireReference(SQLiteClosable.java:31)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:56)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:49)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1236)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1209)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at com.sql.where.main$1.onClick(main.java:62)
    05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2364)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.view.View.onTouchEvent(View.java:4179)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:6591)
   05-23 16:53:16.716: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4544):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3709)
......
```

please assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Main.xml File

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btn1"
    android:text="GetData"></Button>
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tv1"></TextView>
  </LinearLayout>
```

---

DBAdapter.java File

---

```
  package com.testDatabase;

  import android.content.Context;
  import android.database.Cursor;
  import android.database.SQLException;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
  import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
  import android.util.Log;

  public class DBAdapter {
public static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";
public static final String DB_Name = "TestData.db";
public static final String tbl_countries = "countries";

public static final int DB_Version = 1;

private static final String CREATE_TABLE_countries = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
        + tbl_countries + " (id INTEGER);";

private final Context context;

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_Name, null, DB_Version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_countries);
        db.execSQL("insert into " + tbl_countries + "(id) values(1)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + CREATE_TABLE_countries);

        onCreate(db);
    }
}

/* open the database */
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException {
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

/* close the database */
public void close() {
    DBHelper.close();
}

/* get database store path */
public String DataBasePath() {
    return db.getPath();
}

public String getdatatbl() {
    String str1 = "";
    String p = "1";
    // DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select id from countries where id=" + p,
            null); // line no 62.
    if (c != null) {
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                str1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("id"));
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
    if (c != null) {
        c.deactivate();
        c.close();
    }
    return str1;
}

  }
```

---

testDatabase.Java File

---

```
package com.testDatabase;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class testDatabase extends Activity {
    TextView tv1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(testDatabase.this);
                db.open();
                String strid = db.getdatatbl();
                tv1.setText(strid);
                db.close();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

try above code is working ....

Answer (score 1):

You should check if your `SQLiteDatabase`-Object `db` is already closed.

Also, don't simply insert values in the Query stirng, use the `?`:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select id from tbl_countries where id = ?", new String[]{p});
```

---

As I tell it over and over again: To create and Update the Database, an [SQLiteOpenHelper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html) should be used. See the [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).

Comment: I recommend doing in this way, is better

Comment: Did you check if your `SQLiteDatabase`-Object is a `writableDatabase` and if it's not closed already?

Comment: yes, db is closed at last. the `select * from table` is working fine. if i include where clause it cause error.

Comment: This makes no sense. If you close your Database, you can't query anything from it. Post some more code on this please.

Comment: You should use a `SQLiteOpenHelper` to create and update your Database (see my edited post).